# How to get completed signed document from docuSign in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, docusignapi

```
string accountID = "*****";
string envolopeID = "****************";

apiClient = new ApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");
apiClient.SetBasePath("https://account-d.docusign.com/restapi/v2.0/accounts/" + accountID + "/envelopes/" + envolopeID + "/documents/1" );

code = Request.QueryString["code"].ToString();
OAuth.OAuthToken oAuthToken = GenerateAccessToken(IntegratorKey, ClientSecret, code, "userID", "password");

apiClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + oAuthToken.access_token);

EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);
Stream results1 = envelopesApi.GetDocument(accountID, envolopeID, "1");
```

> I am trying to get signed completed document from DocuSign but unable to download it.
> after getting response in result1 gives error as below
> ReadTimeout = 'results1.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
> WriteTimeout = 'results1.WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

> Is my code/logic is correct? How to download signed completed document from DocuSign? Please help to download document.

> I am using ASP.Net web forms and .NET framework 4.5.2

DocuSign.eSign.dll 5.2.0
DocuSign.Integration.Client.dll 1.7.2

Thanking you...

Answer (score 0):

What does `GenerateAccessToken()` do? the "password" is making me think this thing is not the correct way to obtain OAuth 2.0 token. If you generated the token correctly then try this for the first few lines:
For now, your code in demo/developer account, you don't need to set baseURL just to get you working. The URL you had there is wrong.

```
var apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);
apiClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);
```

[Find more about downloading completed documents.](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-downloading-documents)

Comment: Hello Inbar, Thanks for reply
Yes I had generated token correctly. 
I had referred your blog but having query
1) var apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath); here what should be the basePath value?

2)Stream results1 = envelopesApi.GetDocument(accountID, envolopeID, "1");
 this response giving error ReadTimeout = 'results1.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' WriteTimeout = 'results1.WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'.

Please help to download signed document, Thank you.

Comment: https://demo.docusign.net/restapi is the basePath you need to use when in the developer environment

Comment: result1 gives error as below ReadTimeout = 'results1.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' WriteTimeout = 'results1.WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Comment: Thank you for response
Here is my new code, but unable to download signed document.

 code = Request.QueryString["code"].ToString(); 
OAuth.OAuthToken oAuthToken = clsDocuSignAPI.GenerateAccessToken(IntegratorKey, ClientSecret, code, Email, Password); 
apiClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + oAuthToken.access_token); 
var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient); 
Stream results1 = envelopesApi.GetDocument(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["accountID"], envolopeID, "1");

Comment: This code is still using old authentication technique. The Password should never be used in code. Please go to https://devcenterv3test.hqtest.tst/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/, select C#, and you'll get a ZIP file with personalized code - try to run that code. This will be much easier approach.